# How does Xojo UI rendering for desktop work?

Tags: realbasic, xojo

I was wondering if anyone could provide information about how Xojo renders UI for the desktop?

Is Xojo using bindings to make OS specific UI controls available (much like wxWindows)? Or has Xojo custom implementations of all UI controls (much like QT Framework)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither.  They are in fact actual OS native controls that are “bound” but not in the way wxWidgets does, as least in as much as I understand how wxWidgets works.

Xojo is basically a wrapper on top of an actual OS instance - which is why you can use the Handle to pass to OS functions.